# Concatenar dos columnas y sumar sus cantidades mysql

Tags: php, mysql

`function tabla_formato_impresion($ven_id){

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(vd.tb_ventadetalle_can) as cantidad,cg.tb_categoria_nom, m.tb_marca_nom,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pr.tb_presentacion_nom) AS talla,vd.tb_ventadetalle_preunilin, (SUM(vd.tb_ventadetalle_can) * vd.tb_ventadetalle_preunilin) as subtotal FROM tb_venta v
  LEFT JOIN tb_cliente c ON v.tb_cliente_id=c.tb_cliente_id
  INNER JOIN tb_documento d ON v.tb_documento_id=d.tb_documento_id
  INNER JOIN tb_puntoventa pv ON v.tb_puntoventa_id=pv.tb_puntoventa_id
  INNER JOIN tb_ventadetalle vd ON v.tb_venta_id = vd.tb_venta_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_catalogo ct ON vd.tb_catalogo_id = ct.tb_catalogo_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_presentacion pr ON ct.tb_presentacion_id = pr.tb_presentacion_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_producto p ON pr.tb_producto_id = p.tb_producto_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_marca m ON p.tb_marca_id = m.tb_marca_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_categoria cg ON p.tb_categoria_id = cg.tb_categoria_id
  LEFT JOIN tb_unidad un ON ct.tb_unidad_id_bas = un.tb_unidad_id 
  LEFT JOIN tb_servicio s ON vd.tb_servicio_id = s.tb_servicio_id
  where v.tb_venta_id =$ven_id group by cg.tb_categoria_nom,vd.tb_ventadetalle_preunilin,pr.tb_presentacion_nom";

$oCado = new Cado();
$rst=$oCado->ejecute_sql($sql);
return $rst;
```

}`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como sería hacerlo dentro de la funcion group_concat, ya que lo deseo para ponerlo en mi funcion un poco compleja, espero me puedan ayudar, muchar gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola jantoni. Por favor toma la pena de escribir la pregunta en texto, no con una imagen. Gracias.

Comment: si, solo que soy nuevo en Stack y no sé como escribir con esa estructura, lo siento, solo pido ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer esto, tienes que separar el SQL en 2 etapas:

1. Agrupar por `id, name` para conseguir la suma de valores para cada combinación
2. Luego puedes agrupar solo por `id` usando `group_concat` para obtener los resultados deseados.

Para separar la lógica en esas 2 etapas, necesitas usar una tabla derivada. Esta sería la consulta:

```
select id, group_concat(concat(name, ' (', sum_value, ')') order by name separator ', ')
  from (select id, name, sum(value) as sum_value
          from tbl
         group by id, name) t
 group by id
 order by id;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/KBG73785)</kbd>

Comment: Hay alguna manera de compartirte el código de mi función, para que veas en donde deseo integrar GROUP_CONCAT?? o lo copio aquí, muchas gracias

Comment: Agrégalo a tu pregunta. Hay un enlace `editar` debajo de tu pregunta. Aunque no veo cual es el problema. Te contesté exactamente según lo que pusistes en la pregunta. Hasta te dejé un enlace `Demo` donde puedes ver como funciona la consulta usando los datos que pusistes en la pregunta.  Si lo que tienes es un poco diferente, estoy seguro que puedes extraer el principio de la respuesta y aplicarla a tu situación.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que se me hace complejo agregarla a mi función, ya que hago varios INNER JOIN  es una venta. muchas gracias

Comment: Ah por cierto tu ejemplo está muy bien explicado, de hecho que es la respuesta adecuada

Comment: No estoy seguro que pueda ayudarte mucho con la consulta que agregastes. El problema es que no es claro la correspondencia entre las columnas/valores en esa consulta y lo que describistes en la pregunta. Y me parece un problema el que tu `GROUP_CONCAT` trabaje con una sola columna `pr.tb_presentacion_nom`, lo que me da la impresión que en realidad no partes de 2 columnas separadas `Name` y `Value` como lo describes en tu pregunta, sino que ya están concatenadas en una columna. Eso me parece problemático. Tendrías que aclarar mejor donde están los valores necesarios.